# TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ')', got 'social'

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

App Engine is giving me this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ')', got 'social'
template (/srv/templates/base.html:5)
```

I'm not clear why. Here's the beginning of the `base.html` template:

```
{% set navlinks = [('Home', '/'),
                   ('Foo Bar', '/foo-bar'),
                   ('News', '/news'),
                   ('Contact', '/contact)] %}
{% set social_icons = [('social-icons/facebook.html', 'https://www.facebook.com/blah'),
                       ('social-icons/twitter.html', 'https://twitter.com/blah'),
                       ('social-icons/linkedin.html','https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah/')] %}

<!-- remainder of the template... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You transposed closing quote `'` and `)` in

```
('Contact', '/contact')] %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{% set navlinks = [('Home', '/'),
                   ('Foo Bar', '/foo-bar'),
                   ('News', '/news'),
                   ('Contact', '/contact)'] %}
{% set social_icons = [('social-icons/facebook.html', 'https://www.facebook.com/blah'),
                       ('social-icons/twitter.html', 'https://twitter.com/blah'),
                       ('social-icons/linkedin.html','https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah/')] %}

<!-- remainder of the template... -->
```

You missed a close quote after `'/contact)`.